# Constructing a function similar to x^3 between [0,1]

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, functions, discrete-mathematics, continuity

I'm trying to construct a function $f$, in order to normalize a dataset(obviously where all the element come from $[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$.

The big picture is that the envisioned $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ pushes the values that fall to the right side of the initial average of the dataset to $1$, and similarly the values that fall to the left side of the average to $0$. But I want the function to act on the relatively very big and very small numbers in a stronger manner.

So basically the function will look similar to $x^3$'s general pattern. Additionally I'd like to fix some values as follows:

- f(0) = 0,
- f(1) = 1,
- f(avg) = avg, where avg stand for the average of the initial dataset.

Currently I'm having problem with fixing the endpoints. For instance $(x-avg)^3+avg$ would get me $f(avg)=avg$ but not the other two.

I open to using some other formula as long as it adheres to my desired properties.

Please let me know if something regarding the problem description is not clear.

Comment: Your 3 conditions all lie on the line through the origin with slope 1. I can't imagine a function that would satisfy your 3 conditions and also push outliers to the "side"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to make a cubic push outliers to the "side" but I think a cubic satisfying the 3 stipulations you put on $f$ is possible. I will need $3$ parameters to work with since you place $3$ conditions. Suppose $f(x)=x^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$ which is a function with general cubic behaviour. Then $f(0)=0$ implies that $d=0$. $f(1)=1$ implies that $b+c=0$. With these stipulations our function must already take the form:

$$f(x)=x^{3}+bx^{2}-bx$$

Now if we also demand that $f$ fixes a point then we require for some $x$ that:

$x=f(x)=x^{3}+bx^{2}-bx$ so $0=x(x^{2}+bx-(1+b))$

So we must require $x^{2}+bx-(1+b)=0$. This amounts to requiring that:

$b(x-1)=1-x^{2}$ so $b=-1-x$ (This works provided that avg$\,\neq1$. Note that if avg$\,=1$ then $f(1)=1$ deals with this so $b$ is free.). Taking $x=avg$ then we have that $f(x)=x^{3}+(-1-avg)x^{2}-(-1-avg)x$. This gives a cubic type function with the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Please correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that increasing the power of the most dominant term does the trick wrt. "pushing outliers to the sides". Just substituting $x^7$ instead of $x^3$ in your formula got the graph closer to my desired pattern.

Comment: Okay, so for $avg=1/2$ we get $f(x)=x^3-1.5x^2+1.5x$ and then $f(0.2)=0.248$, which means 0.2 was pushed toward the center. Isn't that the opposite of what the OP wants?

Comment: @alexT You're welcome. I don't think that would entirely fix the issue. Whether the function "pushes" outliers to the "side" depends on how $f$ approaches the root $x=0$ and how $f$ passes through the average. I must also avoid adding other roots in $[0,1]$ to $f$ since that affects the pushing property.

Comment: @StumpyLeg I believe I constructed this cubic function based on the other $3$ conditions the OP asked for. To fix the issue of "pushing toward sides" I would most likely need more parameters to control behaviour of the function or perhaps work with an entirely different class of functions.

Comment: @StumpyLeg You're surely right, since in your example $f(0.2) < f(avg)$ I would expect $f(0.2) <= 0.2$ which is apparently not the case. I don't want to "unaccept" the answer but now it's to my understanding that I still need to work on $user71352$'s formula to see if I can get it to what I envision.

Comment: I would like to ask an additional question: If I were to give up on the condition $f(avg) = avg$ (but still keep $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$) will the problem become easier?

Comment: I think the basic problem is that whatever you do, the "push" effect will have to diminish, not increase, near the ends, so that at the limit 0 and 1 do not move at all. I'm assuming you want the function to be continuous....

Comment: @StumpyLeg I guess at this point I don't necessarily persist on a continuous function.

Comment: @StumpyLeg On a second thought I don't agree with your claim that the "push" effect has to diminish near the ends. If we keep the slope relatively small(i.e. the first derivative close to 0) then we may create enough space for f(x) to increase at a greater speeder near the boundaries.

Comment: I may not be thinking about this right, or maybe I don't understand what you're after. But my thought is that if we define "amount of push" for input $x$ as the displacement distance $|f(x)-x|$, then graphically we're talking about the vertical distance between the $f(x)$ curve and the line $y=x$. Those two curves intersect at $x=0$ and $x=1$, and at some point in the middle ($x=avg$ in your original plan). That distance may grow as you move away from the middle, but it has to shrink as you approach $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, for $x$ between 0 and $avg$ you want $f(x)$ to be closer to 0 than $x$ is. In that case,  I would think you want the function to have the general character of $x^{1/3}$ rather than $x^3$, which will pull points toward the center. For instance if $avg = 1/2$, it seems like you'd want something like $f(x)=(x/5-1/10)^{1/3}+1/2$. The vertical scale isn't quite right, but I see you've already accepted another answer, so I'm going to let this go for now. But if you want to push points toward the endpoints *and* want the effect to be stronger for values farther from *avg*, I don't think any simple, *s*-shaped function will do it.

Comment: No, indeed I want cubic behavior. However the blame is on me, I guess I was a little vague in the problem description. Crudely I want three focal points: 0, 1 and the average. So even that I'm pushing the values from average towards the end points, I still want the values which are relatively close to the average to stay in close proximity of the average. Hope it's more clear now.